# Javascript me repite la variable con diferentes valor

Tags: javascript, variables, javascript-objeto, javascript-import

Sabran porque me pasa esto? Envio un dato a esta funcion y el primero lo hace bien ya en el segundo se duplica la variable con el dato impriendo dos, y asi sucesivamente... lo guarde en una variable normal, y pasaba lo mismo decidi usar un input pero aun asi no funciona... ya no se me ocurre mucho, intente darle null y undefined a la variable pero pasaba lo mismo solo que un dato visible y los demas en null o undefined! Los leo atento y muchas gracias de antemano!!

```js
function conjugar(ver){
console.log(ver.innerText);
console.log('funcion');
let boxConju = document.querySelectorAll('.boxConjugador')[0];
boxConju.style.visibility = "visible";
let aconj = document.querySelector('#aConj');
aconj.value = ver.innerText;
console.log(aconj.value);
let verbo2 = aconj.value;
let p1 = document.querySelector('#person1');
let p2 = document.querySelector('#person2');
let p3 = document.querySelector('#person3');
let p4 = document.querySelector('#person4');
let p5 = document.querySelector('#person5');
let p6 = document.querySelector('#person6');        
let Conj2 = document.querySelectorAll('.conj2')[0];
let Conj3 = document.querySelectorAll('.conj3')[0];
let timing1 = document.querySelector('#timePas');
let timing2 = document.querySelector('#timePre');
let timing3 = document.querySelector('#timeFut');
let buttonOk = document.querySelector('#ok');
let buttonNoOk = document.querySelector('#normal');
buttonNoOk.style.visibility = "visible";           
if(verbo2.endsWith("ar")){
    console.log('despues de if');
    console.log(aconj.value);
    p3.addEventListener('click', function(){
        Conj2.style.display = "none";
        Conj3.style.display = "flex";
        timing2.style.background = "#fbff20";
        timing2.style.color = "#070707";
        timing1.style.background = "none";
        timing1.style.color = " #e08f33";
        timing3.style.background = "none";
        timing3.style.color = " #e08f33";
        buttonOk.style.visibility = "visible";
        buttonNoOk.style.visibility = "hidden";
        console.log('p3');
        console.log(aconj.value);
    });  
        timing2.addEventListener('click', function(){
            timing2.style.background = "#fbff20";
            timing2.style.color = "#070707";
            timing1.style.background = "none";
            timing1.style.color = " #e08f33";
            timing3.style.background = "none";
            timing3.style.color = " #e08f33";
            
            buttonOk.style.visibility = "visible";
            console.log('ver1.2');
            console.log(verbo2);
            console.log('ver1.2');
        });
            buttonOk.addEventListener('click', function(){
                buttonNoOk.style.visibility = "hidden";
                buttonOk.style.visibility = "hidden";                    boxConju.style.visibility = "hidden";
                Conj2.style.display = "flex";
                Conj3.style.display = "none";
                verbo2 = '';
                aconj.value.replaceAll(ver.innerText,'');
                verbo2 = aconj.value;
                console.log('ver2');
                console.log(aconj.value);
                console.log('ver2F');
            });
}
```

Comment: Deberías agregar tu código, o un error reproducible para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ahi abajo puse el codigo js en un comentario, disculpa

Comment: estas agregando el evento cada vez que llamas a la funcion. agrega una condicion algo como if( myelement.onclick != null )

Comment: Cual variable te esta dando problemas?